# Write a function takes a two-word string and returns True if both words begin with same letter

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the answer by assigning the split to a variable and then using an if statement. But, I am not able to get it with for loop.

I've tried using for and if statements, but I am unable to get the expected output.

HERE IS THE ERROR CODE.

```py
def animal_crackers(text):
    for letter in text.split():
        if letter[0][0] == letter[1][0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

HERE IS THE SUCCESSFUL CODE.

```py
def animal_crackers(text):
    wordlist = text.split()
    return wordlist[0][0] == wordlist[1][0]
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
TIME TRAVEL --> TRUE
TIME UP --> FALSE
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
TIME TRAVEL --> FALSE
TIME UP --> FALSE
```

Comment: @SubhamDubey when doing it with `for`, `letter` gets the first value in `text.split()`, then you check if the first character int the first character equals the first charcter in the second character (???)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Hope this would help.

```
def checkTwoString(string):
  first, second = string.split(" ")
  if first[0] == second[0]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(checkTwoString("Shishir Shishir"))
```

Comment: this will return `True` if the strings start with the same character

Comment: So @בנימיןכהן bro, this is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

try this (if you have 2 words),

```
>>> def animal_crackers(text):
...   a, b = text.split()
...   return a[0] == b[0]
... 
>>> animal_crackers("TIME TRAVEL")
True
>>> animal_crackers("TIME UP")
False
>>>
```

for multiple words,

```
>>> def animal_crackers(text):
...   txt = text.split()
...   return all([i.startswith(text[0]) for i in txt])
... 
>>> animal_crackers("TXT Travel Time")
True
>>> animal_crackers("TXT Travel Time Up")
False
>>>
```

in your error code (for loop),

you looping each word and trying to access one at a time . so you wont be able to compare both together